# Which extension version allows me to create calico daemonset in vagrant/virtualbox environment

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, calico

I am trying to deploy a vagrant/virtualbox environment with calico as networking framework. However, when doing

```
vagrant up,
```

I get following error:

```
error: unable to recognize "/vagrant/calico/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta2"
```

Previously, I have tried `v1` and `v1beta1`, but got the same error message. Can anyone tell me which repository version carries the daemonset ?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the command:

```
    $ kubectl api-resources | grep daemonsets
    daemonsets                   ds          apps                  true            DaemonSet
```

you can see that DaemonSet needs the "apps" specification.

Try to modify your source YAML file with

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
```